# How can I set my OS X application theme in code?

Tags: xcode, macos, themes

I have an application that Must have light theme all the time. Even if dark mode is enabled on the mac. How can I set my application's theme to always be light?

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation [Choosing a Specific Appearance for Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsappearancecustomization/choosing_a_specific_appearance_for_your_app). Specifically, under the section "Assign a Specific Appearance to Your App", you can assign a value to the `appearance` property of your `NSApplication`:

```
NSApp.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .aqua)
```

Here's the equivalent in Objective C:

```
[NSApp setAppearance:[NSAppearance appearanceNamed:NSAppearanceNameAqua]];
```

If you're linking against an older SDK than 10.14, you'll have to follow the instructions under "Opt Out of Dark Mode". Basically, create a key in your info.plist called `NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance` with a value of `YES`.